# can we extend more than one html in single html template in django?and if yes then how?

Tags: django, django-templates

i have two files... one is base.html and other is home.html

i want to extend both of them on a single index.html template in django.

but it is throwing error *TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template* in browser

Comment: Please see "'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template in browser"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend base in your index.html and use:

```
{% include "path/to/home.html" %}
```